# Send multiple TELNET commands in cmd

Tags: c#, cmd, telnet

```
class Program
{
    public static void ExecuteCommand(string Command)
    {
        ProcessStartInfo ProcessInfo;
        Process Process;

        ProcessInfo = new ProcessStartInfo("cmd.exe", "/C " + Command);
        ProcessInfo.CreateNoWindow = false;
        ProcessInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
        Process = Process.Start(ProcessInfo);
        Process.WaitForExit();

        Process.Close();


    }



    static void Main()
    {

        ExecuteCommand("telnet 169.254.0.1");


    }
}
```

It runs cmd and connects to a specific device via telnet. Next, once connected, it prompts for login and password which I would also like to send, and after that few specific commands. What should I do?

Many thanks!

Answer (score 3):

Simply write to the StandardInput stream.

```
Process process = Process.Start("cmd");

if (process != null)
{
   process.StandardInput.WriteLine("dir");
   process.StandardInput.WriteLine("ping");
   process.StandardInput.WriteLine("something");
}
```

Comment: Maybe I am missing some concept, but the code that you provided doesn't seem to work once the Telnet interface kicks in cmd.